# Unable to use type safe routes in Yesod subsite widget

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm working on a CMS build on top of Yesod for my graduation internship. Currently we are using a subsite (`Core`) to represent the admin area, this `Core` should be reusable between projects so its separated from the master site and has its own repository. It should be possible to include other subsites to integrate into `Core`. Those other subsites should all be able to use the same (admin) layout.

The repositories we use are:
CMS core: https://github.com/lambdacms/lambdacms-core/tree/extensions
CMS media extension: https://github.com/lambdacms/lambdacms-media
Demo Yesod master: https://github.com/lambdacms/ponycms/tree/media

Note that there urls link to specific branches, those are the branches I'm currently using.

Initially I used the function `lambdaCoreLayout` (found in [Foundation.hs](https://github.com/lambdacms/lambdacms-core/blob/extensions/LambdaCms/Core/Foundation.hs)) to provide the correct layout to all handlers within `Core` itself. But I wasn't able to use this function in other subsites. Instead rewriting what already worked I added the function `tryoutLayout` (found in the same file) which works for all subsites and closely resembles `defaultLayoutSub` (which comes with Yesod). However it doesn't allow me to use `getRouteToParent` in any of the handlers to add type safe routes to the widgets.

take to following snippet for example:

```
getAdminHomeR :: CoreHandler Html
getAdminHomeR = do
  tp <- getRouteToParent
  tryoutLayout [whamlet|@{tp AdminHomeR}|]
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Could not deduce (master ~ Core)
from the context (LambdaCmsAdmin master)
  bound by the type signature for
             getAdminHomeR :: LambdaCmsAdmin master =>
                              HandlerT Core (HandlerT master IO) Html
  at LambdaCms/Core/Handler/Home.hs:17:18-33
  ‘master’ is a rigid type variable bound by
           the type signature for
             getAdminHomeR :: LambdaCmsAdmin master =>
                              HandlerT Core (HandlerT master IO) Html
           at <no location info>
Expected type: WidgetT
                 Core
                 IO
                 (yesod-core-1.4.2:Yesod.Routes.Class.Route master
                  -> [(Text, Text)] -> Text)
  Actual type: WidgetT
                 Core
                 IO
                 (yesod-core-1.4.2:Yesod.Routes.Class.Route
                    (HandlerSite (WidgetT Core IO))
                  -> [(Text, Text)] -> Text)
Relevant bindings include
  tp :: yesod-core-1.4.2:Yesod.Routes.Class.Route Core
        -> yesod-core-1.4.2:Yesod.Routes.Class.Route master
    (bound at LambdaCms/Core/Handler/Home.hs:20:3)
  getAdminHomeR :: HandlerT Core (HandlerT master IO) Html
    (bound at LambdaCms/Core/Handler/Home.hs:19:1)
In the first argument of ‘(>>=)’, namely ‘getUrlRenderParams’
In the first argument of ‘tryoutLayout’, namely
  ‘((getUrlRenderParams
     >>=
       (\ urender_agTZ
          -> (asWidgetT . toWidget)
               (toHtml (\ u_agU0 -> urender_agTZ u_agU0 [] (tp AdminHomeR))))))’
```

If I'm correct this error suggests that `getRouteToParent` trying to return a function which tries to generate a `Route Core` instead of a `Route master`. I tried different places to put `tp <- getRouteToParent` but I haven't been able to get it to work.

My own knowledge of Haskell and Yesod is limited and I haven't been able to find the solution or pointers in the right direction. Is there something I'm missing or is there another way this should be approached?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want your `tryoutLayout` function to take a value of type `WidgetT master IO ()`, not `WidgetT Core IO ()`, to allow you to embed master site routes.

Comment: Actually I just want the widgets to be able to include routes for the subsite the widget exists in. However I thought a route should always be a `Route master`, thats why I used `getRouteToParent`. Now I'm using just the core route (`@{AdminHomeR}`) which works fine. Thanks for this answer because it made me realise the `getRouteToParent` wasn't needed.